# Java uses wrong time/date in log4j on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, datetime, log4j, ubuntu-10.04

i have a problem with my server date configuration and java running log4j and solr on ubuntu 10.04.

System time is CEST.
date command output:

```
# date
Di 31. Jul 14:05:02 CEST 2012
```

but the time in the logs of my application logging with log4j is:

```
2012-07-31 12:05:02
```

i use this line in my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %t %c - %m%n
```

Now i build a jar to test the time containing basically two lines of code:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date));
```

this gives me the expected wrong output:

```
# java -jar javaDate.jar
31.07.2012 12:05:02
```

if i use the virtual machine parameter for timezone it works correctly

```
java -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin -jar javaDate.jar 
31.07.2012 14:05:02
```

but if i use the same parameter to start the application that is using log4j is still get the wrong timestamps in my log.
why????

Comment: Your JVM is set to show the UTC time.

Comment: @galuano1 yes but why does the -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin parameter work for my test jar but not for the application using log4j, and how can i configure my jvm to always use system time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of log4j you should be able to use the EnhancedPatternLayout if you add:

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
```

to your config and use

```
%d{ISO8601}{Europe/Berlin}
```

in your layout.

Comment: i changed the line to log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}{Europe/Berlin} %p %t %c - %m%n
but now i get the same wrong timestamp but with string {Europe/Berlin} appended at the end:
2012-07-31 12:46:05,163{Europe/Berlin} INFO main ...

Comment: my version is 1.2.17, is this not recent enough?

Comment: That should be fine, I'll update my answer - remembered you also need to use a different Layout class...